# Safari 6.0 Rendering problems

Tags: safari

I have a 2011 MacBook Pro with OS X 10.8 I have noticed a lot of rendering issues in Gmail, and Google instant. It seems related to JavaScript. Has anyone had this problem and is there a solution?

Comment: "Rendering problems" is a bit of a broad description. If possible, a screenshot might provide a better idea of the problem you are experiencing. Also, why do you believe it is related to JavaScript?

Comment: Apparently the problem still exists with 10.8.1. I am still seeing the same rendering issues as 10.8.

Comment: If anyone with this issue can edit the question to show a screen shot or further clarification that may help others with this issue. Also, making a new question that explains how the solution here isn't working is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: I'm on OS X 10.8.1 and Safari 6.0 (8536.25) and am still having intermittent blank areas with GMail, like a redraw should have happened in a certain area but didn't. Here's an example: http://kong.dreamhosters.com/grabs/5s/s8cepkq8owo4w.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common issue with Safari 6.0 (screen tearing, text not showing up, etc.). I've updated to 10.8.1 developer build and can confirm that I haven't had the issue pop up since I've updated.

The update will be going live in the next few weeks and that should help fix any tearing issues.

Comment: Still have white rectangle popping on top of gmail in 10.8.1. Back to Chrome for now. Sigh ((

Comment: I'm on 10.8.2 now, and still have this problem. I can't even send a message in Facebook properly, because the rendered graphics don't seem to be cleaned properly in the next rendering loop. Highlighting the whole page fixes it, but it's still really annoying.